# Сборка Qt из исходников в Linux, Ubuntu 18 (не отрабатывает make)

Tags: linux, qt, qt5, компиляция, кросс-компиляция

Решил установить Qt 5.10.1 из исходников. qt-everywhere-src-5.10.1.tar.xz
Устанавливал по [мануалу](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/linux-deployment.html).

1. разархивировал архив  qt-everywhere-src-5.10.1.tar.xz.
2. вызвал команду в консоли

   > comp@comp:~/qt_re_bild/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.1$ ./configure

Выдал : `Эта программа собрана для x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`

3. Вызвал команду make и всякие производные (от безнадёги ;_;). Увы третья операция не прошла, стал искать make даже не понял куда linux его положил.

   > comp@comp:~/qt_re_bild/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.1$ make

**Не могу найти make файл!! Совершенно не понял где он лежит**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Также побывал скомпилировать под ресбери (АРМ linux) в Ubuntu 18, в обще почему то не пошло.
попробовал

> comp@comp:~/qt_re_bild/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.1$ ./configure  -platform linux-arm-gnueabi-g++

Но не заработало, выкинуло ошибку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
$ ./configure
...
Note: Also available for Linux: linux-clang linux-icc

Note: No wayland-egl support detected. Cross-toolkit compatibility disabled.

WARNING: Python version 2 (2.7.5 or later) is required to build QtWebEngine.

WARNING: gperf is required to build QtWebEngine.

WARNING: bison is required to build QtWebEngine.

WARNING: flex is required to build QtWebEngine.

ERROR: The OpenGL functionality tests failed!
You might need to modify the include and library search paths by editing QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL[_ES2],
QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL[_ES2] and QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL[_ES2] in the mkspec for your platform.

Check config.log for details.
```

Comment: ну так чем закончился запуск `./configure`? концовку хотя бы приведите: warning-и, error-ы, note-ы.

Comment: когда видишь вопросы с подомным оформлением начинаешь метаться между праведным гневом с пожеланиями адского пламени и жалостливым истеричным плачем «я умоляю! пожалуйста! приводите текстовую информацию текстом, а не картинками!»

Comment: @alexanderbarakin  извините можете, проверить мой ответ.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, Alt+PrintScreen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вам, собственно, про всё и написали в конце вывода скрипта `configure`:

> ```
> WARNING: Python version 2 (2.7.5 or later) is required to build QtWebEngine.
> WARNING: gperf is required to build QtWebEngine.
> WARNING: bison is required to build QtWebEngine.
> WARNING: flex is required to build QtWebEngine.
> ERROR: The OpenGL functionality tests failed!
> ```

надо установить пакеты `python`, `gperf`, `bison`, `flex` и `libgl1-mesa-dev` (последний в разных дистрибутивах может называться чуть иначе).

после этого перезапустить [провалившиеся проверки](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.10/config_help.txt#L69):

```
$ ./configure -recheck
```

когда устраните недочёты, конфигурация завершится удачно (в т.ч. будет создан и *makefile*) и прямо открытым текстом будет предложено запускать сборку программой *make*